# How to create spinboxs and receive int information from them rather then str in python

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, int, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a calculator program which gives you an estimate of how much money you spend on gas each year. To be able to run the program I need to run an algorithm which takes information(in int form) from the spinboxes. When I try to run the code, it says that I can't multiply non strings(ints) by strings. How do I change the spin boxes to receive info as ints rather then strings. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
var = IntVar()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=335)
canvas.pack()

def selection():
    sel = "Price: " + int(scale.get() * w.get() * s.get() / 100)
    label.config(text=sel)

label1 = Label(tk, text="Current Gas Price($/l)")
label1.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
w = Spinbox(tk, from_=0, to=1, width=5)
w.place(relx=0.58, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
s = Spinbox(tk, from_=1, to=99, width=5)
label45 = Label(tk, text=".")
label45.place(relx=0.705, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
s.place(relx=0.82, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
label2 = Label(tk, text="Average Yearly Gas Cost", font=('Helvetica', 25))
label2.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, anchor=CENTER)
scale = Scale(tk, variable=var, from_=0, to=50000, resolution=500,       orient=HORIZONTAL, length=250)
scale.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.45, anchor=CENTER)
label3 = Label(tk, text="Kilometre Range")
label3.place(relx=0.165, rely=0.47, anchor=CENTER)
label4 = Label(tk, text=" Highway Fuel efficency(l/100km)")
label4.place(relx=0.29, rely=0.65, anchor=CENTER)
 E3 = Spinbox(tk, from_=5, to=17, width=5)
 E3.place(relx=0.68, rely=0.65, anchor=CENTER)
 label10 = Label(tk, text=".")
label10.place(relx=0.79, rely=0.65, anchor=CENTER)
E4 = Spinbox(tk, from_=0, to=10, width=5)
E4.place(relx=0.91, rely=0.65, anchor=CENTER)
B1 = Button(tk, text="Calculate", command=selection)
B1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.8, anchor=CENTER)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's the actual traceback? I'm sure it isn't "can't multiply non strings(ints) by strings"

Comment: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: Have you tried converting the strings to numbers after you .get them but before trying to do calculations with them? Also your code could really use some white space and better names.

Comment: @abccd          that is the error it gives us

Comment: @jonrsharpe     How would you convert it before hand

Comment: How does one convert any string to a number in Python? If you don't know, what's stopping you searching for it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change `sel` to this:

```
sel = "Price: " + str(float(scale.get()) * float(w.get()) * float(s.get()) / 100)
```

Which converts `scale.get()` and `w.get()` and `s.get()` to `floats` before multiplying. After all, what you did was changing it to `int` after the `str`'s multiplied(which is not possible).

And just a side note, don't name your root `tk`, since it could get confused with `tkinter` when people do `import tkinter as tk`, which is very common.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Now I am trying to make some of the spin boxes together for dollars plus cents. Would I display it by just putting float(s.get()) + float(w.get()) or another way